# can i create instances in Openstack using vagrant or docker?

Tags: vagrant, docker, openstack

I want to automate creating multiply instances in Openstack using puppet but I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to create instances in Openstack without going to the site and loging in. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). Have a look at the [vagrant-openstack](https://github.com/cloudbau/vagrant-openstack-plugin) plugin provided by Cloudbau. The plugin is based on [vagrant-rackspace](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace) which can be used to create instance on the Rackspace Cloud Servers platform. Further details and an example Vagrantfile are available in the [README file](https://github.com/cloudbau/vagrant-openstack-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

It's not possible with [Docker](http://www.docker.com/) because Docker is not a tool to manage instance on cloud platforms like OpenStack. Docker is a tool to manage applications inside containers using [LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/).

Comment: I tried using Vagrant openstack plugin but I kept running into so many errors, I decided to look for other alternatives

Comment: You are explicitly asking for a solution with Vagrant or Docker. With Docker it's not possible because Docker is not at tool to manage instances on a cloud platform like OpenStack.

Comment: I need an easy tutorial to use Vagrant open stack plugin

Comment: Have you not read the README file available at https://github.com/cloudbau/vagrant-openstack-plugin/blob/master/README.md?

Comment: I did, but I can not get it to work, after 2 days of messing with it.